# Unwrap a Property Value into a Property

Tags: javascript

How do you unwrap changeField value into an object ?

```
    let dataChanges = new Map();
    let newValue = "brown";
    let changeId = 5;
    let changeField = "haircolor";
        
    dataChanges.set(changeId, { id: changeId, changeField: newValue });
        
    console.log(dataChanges);
```

The result of this is:   `value: {id: 5, changeField: 'brown'}`

But what I'm trying to make it do is this:  `value: {id: 5, haircolor : 'brown'}`

Answer (score 3):

With ES6 bracket notation, you can set the key dynamically with the variable value.

```
{ id: changeId, [changeField]: newValue }
```

```js
 

    let dataChanges = new Map();
    let newValue = "brown";
    let changeId = 5;
    let changeField = "haircolor";
        
    dataChanges.set(changeId, { id: changeId, [changeField]: newValue });
```